# Why fcntl() is not blocking on F_SETLKW in WSL?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fcntl

I was trying to figure out different types of ways to lock a file in linux and i just came across fcntl().

According to man page, fcntl() with `F_SETLKW` should block if a conflicting lock is held on the file. So i created the following code snippet and ran on two terminals.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

//lock.c is the file name
void lock() {
    struct flock fl;

    fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    fl.l_len = 10;
    fl.l_start = 0;
    fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    fl.l_pid = getpid();

    int fd1 = open("lock.c", O_RDWR);
    printf("Try to set the lock!\n");
    int res = fcntl(fd1, F_SETLKW, &fl);
    printf("Set the lock with status: %d\n", res);

    sleep(20);
}

int main(void)
{
    lock();
}
```

My expected outcome is the first process should print out both lines immediately, while the second process should only print out the first line and wait util the first process finishes sleeping then print out the second line.

But it turned out that both of the processes immediately print out both lines and start sleeping. Am i misunderstanding how fcntl() works or is there a bug in the code?

```c
$./lock
Try to set the lock!
Set the lock with status: 0
```

Comment: Works for me. How are you running the second process?

Comment: That said, I have *never* used ranged-based locks in real life. The trend these days seems to be for daemons.

Comment: @o11c Well i just have a second tab in the terminal. In the first tab, enter ./lock. After i see two lines of output, i go to the second tab, enter ./lock.

Comment: Should not you specify pid there? **fl.l_pid = getpid();**

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny added, still the same outcome

Comment: Actually your code works for me as well. I'm testing it on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Are you sure you are not trying to lock files with the same name but in different folders?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny `l_pid` is a *return* value when `F_GETLK` fails, it is not relevant as input.

Comment: @o11c, I already figured it out. I just saw it assigned somewhere once. So I copy-pasted someone's mistake into advice. Shame on me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i think i found the issue. I am using the WSL 2 (updated yesterday) with Ubuntu subsystem from Windows 10 store. And fcntl() doesn't support/has bug F_SETLK in WSL, yet. It's a known issue for a fairly long time.

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1927